# PyQt: connecting widget with a function with argument

Tags: python, pyqt4

So, I found out it can be done using python's `lambda`, but the problem is, if I put a variable inside `lambda`, it will take it's last value, which I don't want to happen. So, is this possible to do with for loop or I need to do it manually?
Short code example is here:

```
import os,sys,time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,600,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")

        self.btns=[]
        layout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        for i in range(5):
            self.btns.append(QtGui.QPushButton(str(i),self))
            self.btns[i].pressed.connect(lambda: self.example(i))
            layout.addWidget(self.btns[i])

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def example(self,i):
        print(i)#no matter which button is clicked, it prints 4 in this example


app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI=Widget()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: self.btns[i].pressed.connect(partial(self.example, i))...........https://www.learnpython.org/en/Partial_functions, lambda will take the last on in loop

Comment: Can you explain your question better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from functools import partial
self.btns[i].pressed.connect(partial(self.example, i))
```

lambdas in python are closures, so it will take the last on in loop